# how get attribute value of xml node while parsing in android (Using BaseFeedParser)

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am developing an application where I want to parse a xml. my node structure ia as follow

```
<MainNode title="firstNode">
    <Subnode>value</Subnode>
</MainNode>
```

Now I want to read title of first node but I don't get it how to read this. Does any one done this before. Please give some example.

Thank You

Note--Below code tried

```
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String name,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    super.startElement(uri, localName, name, attributes);
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(MAIN)){
        this.RegisterMessage = new RegisterMessage();
        Log.v("AttValue",attributes.getValue("title").toString());
    }       
}
```

I tested this code in debugger but control doesn't came to if statement.

Note:-- SAX Parser is looking more complicated for me so I just shifted for BaseFeedParser it not solved my question but it is working as I want & still the question is same how to read nodes attribute in BaseFeedParser.

Comment: which Parser have you implemented?

Comment: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/org.xml.sax/GetAttr.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow my article series on Android XML : http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/android-xml-adventure-parsing-data-with-saxparser/

Very easy for beginners, full source code provided, line by line instructions :)

Answer (score 2):

Inside your handler class, implement parsing for MainNode as:

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

   if (localName.equals("MainNode"))
   {
      /** Get attribute value */
      String strTitle = attributes.getValue("title");
      Log.i("Title",strTitle);
   }
}
```

Comment: @SandipJadhav There is no other way to parse this attribute. This code works fine. Check the code for your other mistakes. Be patience.